# HowTo: Using MvcContrib.Pagination without using MvcContrib.Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

This started as a question, but turned into a solution as I did some experimenting!  So I thought I would share this with you all.  My question WAS:

**How to use MvcContrib.Pagination without using MvcContrib.Grid View?**

My answer is below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am building a Help Desk Ticketing System (I am kind of a C# newbie - got many pointers from NerdDinner) and I wish to use some sort of paging library to help with the view.  I found MvcContrib.Pagination and I got it to work for a view.  My view does NOT use MvcContrib.Grid because it is custom.

Scaled down version of my view **List.aspx** :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyProject.Areas.HelpDesk.Models.hd_Ticket>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Areas.HelpDesk.Controllers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.Pagination" %>

<h2>Help Desk Tickets (showing <%= Model.Count() %> of <%= ViewData["totalItems"] %>)</h2>     

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <h3><%= Html.Encode(item.Subject)%></h3>
<% } %>

<p><%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model)%></p>
```

My controller (part) **TicketController.cs** :

```
TicketRepository ticketRepository = new TicketRepository();

public ActionResult List(int? page, int? pageSize)
{
    IPagination<hd_Ticket> tickets = null;

    int dPageSize = 50;
    int totalItems;

    tickets = ticketRepository.GetTickets().ToList().AsPagination(page ?? 1, pageSize ?? dPageSize);
    ViewData["totalItems"] = tickets.TotalItems;

    return View("List", tickets);
}
```

I am using the repository pattern which is returning the results as IQueryable.  Here is part of the **TicketRepository.cs** file:

```
public class TicketRepository
{
    private HelpDeskDataContext db = new HelpDeskDataContext();

    public IQueryable<hd_Ticket> FindAllTickets()
    {
        return from ticket in db.hd_Tickets
               orderby ticket.CreatedDate descending
               select ticket;
    }
}
```

All this may be trivial to some, but if someone like me is trying to learn C# and ASP.NET MVC and paging, then this may be useful.  I recommend newbies to do the NerdDinner tutorial found at:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

:)

Comment: You shouldn't call ToList() before AsPagination(). ToList() builds a list of all the items in your query, so you're still getting everything from the repository even if later you're only displaying a subset of that on the page.